# Sending individual user data back to client from the server [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openid, steam

I am making a website where users login through Steam. I am able to get their information (such as profile picture and user name) but I've been struggling with sending it back to the client. The json of the user logging in is held within `req.user` inside of a get request. How would I go about sending the users info from the server to the client of the user that has just logged in?

This is my current code -

```
// Required to get data from user for sessions
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
// Initiate Strategy
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/api/auth/steam/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/',
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }, function (identifier, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            profile.identifier = identifier;
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'LoopTrades',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600000
    }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
app.get('/api/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam', {failureRedirect: '/'}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
app.get('/api/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', {failureRedirect: '/'}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/pages/deposit.html');
});
```

Comment: you'd do so in `res.send` I guess - which would not be easy when you redirect of course

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question and I've been trying to work it out for hours but, where exactly is ```res.send``` being sent?

Comment: `res.send` is response to client request

Comment: you say `I am able to get their information` ... where do you get this information? no sign of it in your code

Comment: When they log in through steam using http://localhost:3000/api/auth/steam their information is then saved as a json within req.user. I can console.log(req.user) and get a response with all their information when a user logs in.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm asking the wrong questions ... so `req.user` in `app.get('/'` has the required info? what type of value is `req.user`? what does the client get in the response since you `res.send(req.user);` the client must get something, right?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've managed to fix it by changing the location the json is stored in for the client and then calling that location.